# Blender detects 2 gpu's but only renders on 1

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

i have 2 Gtx 1080 Ti's gpu's and both are shown in the User Preferences->System TAB but while rendering it only shows 1 tile.

The issue occured some days ago and before that it worked fine with 2 tiles.

[image: cuda]

I already reinstalled blender and the graphics driver.

I also found that i can't only check 1 card in the Preferences->System TAB, it selects or deselcts only both of them.

[image: select error]

I also tried with the latest 2.8 test release, its the same behavor.

I was on Blender version 2.79 when it started to happen and now i am on 2.79b and it is still occuring.

I am on the latest nvidia driver.
I am on win 10.

[image: select error]

Both gpu's running in SLI, i don't think that would be a problem as it always worked under sli.

Comment: "*Both gpu's running in SLI*" < That's the issue right there. As far as I know SLI or Crossfire or any other GPU pairing technology make it so multiple GPUs are presented as a single entity to at the operating system level, not even sure how Blender can even see both

Comment: yep, the 'L' in SLI stands for Link.  your OS sees those two cards linked-together as one.  Blender should render faster when you disable SLI mode, because it can then multi-thread tiles.  https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001167.htm

Comment: Strange, disable sli did work but i am 100% sure it worked with sli tuned on before, well thank you anyway

Comment: SLI and cycles do not go together.

Comment: You probably suffered from a windows / nvidia update that changed the sli profile or something like this. Anyway, I would never enable sli for working in blender since the only you can expect (if ever it worked) is having 0.80 of the performance of your two cards together rendering one tile at a time. Windows 10 is often messing around with stuff while updating, it's a variable multiplier by itself and now you remind me why Ubuntu is also on my system.